# Making structural changes to very large tables in an online environment

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

So here's what I'm facing.

**The Problem**

- A large table, with ~230,000,000
  rows.
- We want to change the
  clustering index and primary key of
  this table to a simple bigint
  identity field. There is one other
  empty field being added to the table,
  for future use.
- The existing table
  has a composite key. For the sake of
  argument, let's say it's 2 bigint's.
  The first one may have 1 or 10,000
  'children' in the 2nd part of the
  key.

**Requirements**

- Minimal downtime, like preferably the
  length of time it takes to run
  SP_Rename.
- Existing rows may change
  while we're copying data. The updates
  must be reflected in the new table.

**Ideas**

1. Put a trigger on existing table,
   to update row in new table if it
   already exists there.
2. Iterate through original table, copying data
   into new table ~10,000 at a time.
   Maybe 2,000 of the first part of the
   old key.
3. When the copy is
   complete, rename the old table to
   "ExistingTableOld" and the new one
   from "NewTable" to "ExistingTable".
   This should allow stored procs to
   continue to run without intervention

Are there any glaring omissions in the plan, or best practices I'm ignoring?

Comment: Maybe stupid, but remember to add your old key as a key in the new table, preferably a unique one. As long as you don't have anything enumerating indexes and expecting a specific primary key you should be good to go.

Comment: The *only* additional index I have in my initial pass at the new table is the old key. I'll add all the other supporting ones after I've migrated the data. edit: added the word "additional", I obviously have the new clustered index

Answer (score 1):

Difficult problem. Your plan sounds good, but I'm not totally sure you really need to batch the query as long as you run it in a transaction isolation level of READ UNCOMMITTED to stop  locks being generated.

Comment: If the isolation level is READ UNCOMMITTED, and there is a trigger on rows that are getting updated before the transaction is fully complete, how does SQL unwind that?  e.g. row 1 million is altered, before I'm done with the single update (if I'm not 'batching'), does the trigger to update the new table wait around? I can't even think of a way to actually simulate this with a smaller dataset.

Comment: It shouldn't wait around, because there's no lock in place (READ UNCOMMITTED is the same as adding the WITH (NOLOCK) option). You should be able to make sure by adding a long WAITFOR xxx inside your transaction to make sure, and firing some triggers in the meantime.

Comment: Making a schema change like this with READ UNCOMMITTED? That's nuts: nothing like picking up partially complete and/or ghost transactions to really foul up your data. Data integrity is the whole point here: you really don't want the bad/bogus data that READ UNCOMMITTED gives you.

Answer (score 1):

My experience making big schema changes is big changes are best done during a maintenance window—at night/over a weekend—when users are booted off the system. Just like running `dbcc checkdb` with the repair option. Then, when things go south, you have the option to roll back to the full backup that you providentially made right before starting the upgrade.

**Item #3** on your list: Renaming the old/new tables. You'll probably want to recompile the stored procedures/views. My experience is that execution plans are bound against the object ids rather than object names.

Consider table `dbo.foo`: if it is renamed to `dbo.foo_old`, any stored procedures or user-defined functions won't necessarily error out until the dependent object is recompiled and its execution plan rebound. Cached execution plans continue to work perfectly fine.

`sp_recompile` is your friend.